# JNI convert jbytearay into std::string

Tags: java, android, c++

I've used https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769851 and adapted for C++ as follows:

```
    jsize num_bytes = env->GetArrayLength(message);
    char *buffer = new char(num_bytes + 1);

    if (!buffer) {
        // handle allocation failure ...
        //throw error?
        return 1;
    }

    // obtain the array elements
    jbyte* elements = env->GetByteArrayElements(message, NULL);

    if (!elements) {
        // handle JNI error ...
        //throw error?
        return 2;
    }

    // copy the array elements into the buffer, and append a terminator
    memcpy(buffer, elements, num_bytes);
    buffer[num_bytes] = 0;

    std::string m(buffer, num_bytes + 1);

    // Do not forget to release the element array provided by JNI:
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(message, elements, JNI_ABORT);
```

I had to change `char *buffer = malloc(num_bytes + 1);` to `char *buffer = new char(num_bytes + 1);` because of C++ errors. Why it won't work in C++ by the way?

Well, so with this code I get a crash. I think it's probably related to this change I made, because `env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(message, elements, JNI_ABORT);` might be releasing it as if it were allocated by `malloc`.

How should this code in C++ work?

Answer (score 1):

Notice the brackets (round vs. square) you've chosen.

```cpp
char *buffer = new char(num_bytes + 1);
```

... creates one `char` that has a value of `num_bytes + 1`.

```cpp
char *buffer = new char[num_bytes + 1];
```

... creates an array with `num_bytes + 1` number of `char`s. That should be it.

---

Related:

- [Why does C++ require a cast for malloc() but C doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3477741/12323248)
- [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184537/12323248)

Answer (score 1):

`new char(N)` allocates a single `char` with a value of `N`. You want an array of `N` characters, so use `new char[N]` instead.

That being said, you don’t actually need the `char[]` array at all. You can construct the `std::string` using the Java byte array elements as-is, eg:

```cpp
jsize num_bytes = env->GetArrayLength(message);

// obtain the array elements
jbyte* elements = env->GetByteArrayElements(message, NULL);
if (!elements) {
    // handle JNI error ...
    //throw error?
    return 1;
}

// copy the array elements into the string
std::string m(reinterpret_cast<char*>(elements), num_bytes);

// Do not forget to release the element array provided by JNI
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(message, elements, JNI_ABORT);
```

Or, at the very least, you can presize the `std::string` and then copy the byte array elements into the string’s own memory buffer, eg:

```cpp
jsize num_bytes = env->GetArrayLength(message);

// obtain the array elements
jbyte* elements = env->GetByteArrayElements(message, NULL);
if (!elements) {
    // handle JNI error ...
    // throw error?
    return 1;
}

// copy the array elements into the string
std::string m(num_bytes, ‘\0’);
std::copy_n(elements, num_bytes, m.begin());

// Do not forget to release the element array provided by JNI
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(message, elements, JNI_ABORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically cast the `malloc` to `char*`:

```
char *buffer = (char *) malloc(num_bytes + 1);
```

[**C won't need this, but C++ would**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Your linked example uses **`C`**, and that's whats causing the *subtle*  difference here.

The **`C++`** compiler assumes that `malloc()` returns an `int`, leading to inconsistencies in type sizing for the **destination pointer type** (`char<-int`)